# Получить информацию о js-файле, как аналог Reflection в javascript

Tags: javascript, рефлексия

Вначале немного отвлекусь от файлов, тем самым пояснив, что я хочу получить в конечном итоге. В php есть расширение Reflection, позволяющее вывести информацию о коде и его элементах (классах, функциях и т.д.)

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

...

$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('\\MyNameSpace\\MyClass'); //Создаёт отражение класса
$reflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod('MyClass', 'myMethod');  //Создаёт отражение метода
```

Таким образом, через такие отражения можно достать информацию об элементах кода. Что касается php, могу поделиться своим примером: https://github.com/tivewsalaeharad/study/blob/main/src/functions.php

Но касаемо js, хотел бы узнать, существует ли какой-нибудь способ такого отражения. Я понимаю, что в php большую роль играет, и существенно облегчает PSR-стандарт автозагрузки, если, конечно библиотеки написаны в соответствии со стандартами, что, к счастью, в большинстве случаев, поэтому, один файл - это один класс. Но в js такого стандарта как я понимаю нет, и в одном файле могут присутствовать несколько классов, а также куча функций. Поэтому целевой вопрос следующий, существуют ли в javascript подобные функции:

- `allClasses('path/to/module.js'); // Вывести перечень классов из module.js`
- `allFunctions('path/to/module.js'); // Вывести перечень функций из module.js`
- `allFields(MyClass); // Вывести перечень (вообще любых) составляющих класса MyClass`

Сразу сделаю оговорку: понятие класса в javascript очень относительное, вплоть до того, что класс не обязательно может быть объявлен через конструкцию `class`, тем не менее, есть ли какой-то способ преобразовать js-файл в какое-то резюме или оглавление или граф логической структуры?

Comment: Ничего такого нет. Если у вас реально есть файл (и дело происходит на сервере) то есть парсеры JS и даже готовые документаторы, например JSDoc, но что бы они хорошо работали нужно писать код и комментарии специального вида.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, на локальном сервере. У меня есть библиотека в node_modules и мне нужно получить её резюме, т.е. какой она имеет функционал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по описанию, вам нужен парсер javascript-кода. Вот пример такого: https://www.npmjs.com/package/acorn

Поищите в поиске npm "code parser". Я уверен, вы найдете что вам нужно. https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=Code%20Parser

Comment: Насчёт acorn - спасибо, но проблема в том, что он токенизирует только простые скрипты. Когда я пытаюсь пропустить через него например Vue.js, ругается: "'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'"

Comment: @PavelSumarokov, это ошибка не связана с Vue.js, парсер вам прямо говорит что вы должны указать опцию `sourceType: 'module'`

Comment: Я понял. Большое спасибо. Отличный инструмент

Answer (score 0):

По поводу первых двух. Не имею представления разве что парсить сам файл.

**- allClasses('path/to/module.js'); // Вывести перечень классов из module.js** - ????

**- allFunctions('path/to/module.js'); // Вывести перечень функций из module.js** - ????

**- allFields(MyClass); // Вывести перечень (вообще любых) составляющих класса MyClass** - Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(myClass)